# How to fixing error when preview result in BIRT viewed?

Tags: report, reporting, birt

I want to show the preview result of BIRT using Classic Models Inc. Sample Database with this query in data set:
    select *
    from CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS

But when I want to show the preview result there is an error :

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.runDataset(DatasetPreviewTask.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.execute(DatasetPreviewTask.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.<init>(PreparedQuery.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.<init>(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.<init>(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQueryUtil.newInstance(PreparedQueryUtil.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl.prepare(DataEngineImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.extractQuery(DatasetPreviewTask.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:309)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptOrFnNode cannot be found by org.eclipse.birt.data_4.4.2.v201501161327
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, it looks like you are trying to preview the report using eclipse birt designer.

You may want to try and configure the data source in the birt designer to point to the right database.

Try viewing the preview results from the data set console in the birt designer and it should retrieve the records that you would like to see in the report there.

Hope it helps.